# L5.5 relationship of pivot table with another model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my application, a model `Device` has a many-to-many relationship with model `Task`.
A combination of Device and Task could be assigned to a various number of model `User`.
example: `Device` A has a Task `Check something` and this should be done by `User` Frank and Steven.

From my point of view, this should be a "standard problem", but so far I could not find a proper solution.

Right now, I use following workaround:
a) added an unique ID `id` to the `device_task` pivot table
b) query `id` from the pivot table
c) create a new table `device_task_user` which contains `user_id` and `device_task_id`
b) use query builder to get/add users

But I am really not happy with this approche.

Would it be possible, that the pivot table also extends Model and then have a one-to-many relationship with `User`?
Or would you suggest to add a json colum to the pivot table and store the users there?

Any idea would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be possible, that the pivot table also extends Model

Yes, it's possible. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships):

> If you would like to define a custom model to represent the intermediate table of your relationship, you may call the using method when defining the relationship. All custom models used to represent intermediate tables of relationships must extend the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` class

You also can create a new `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()` relationships between `Task` and `Device` models and use them as well as existing `belongsToMany` relationship. And you'll need to define a new relationship between pivot model and `User` model to be able to get data by device, task or user.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the first part of your answer (where you refer to the doc) but the second part of your answer confuses me: I am not clear how this could solve my problem

Comment: @titonior in the second part I'm trying to tell you that you can create additional relationships to be able easily get the data.

Comment: Sorry, I probably still don’t get it. Do you mean the following: a) make a new model DeviceTask for the pivot table b) define a one-to-many relationship between Device and DeviceTask c) define a one-to-many relationship between Task and DeviceTask d) finally define a one-to-many relationship between DeviceTask and User ??

Comment: @titonior yes, and you'll also be able to use many-to-many relationship at the same time when it's more convenient.

Comment: Alexey, I did exactly as you have suggested to me and it is working perfectly. - Thanks a lot once again!!

Answer (score 2):

Modify many-to-many relationship to hold an extra field  `user_id`

```
class Device extends Model
{

  public function tasks()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Task::class,
        'device_task',
        'device_id',
        'task_id'
    )->withPivot('user_id');
  }

}
```

And when updating do like this in controller

```
$device->tasks()->attach([$taskId]=>['user_id']=>$userId);
```

And of-course you need `DeviceTask` model and also   a `has-many` relationship between `User` model and `DeviceTask` model to get user's task

Comment: Thanks! I know that this is possible but since a device/task could have more than one user it would require a json column, right? Would this be a best practice approach or not?

Comment: In that case it's  better to have a many-to-many relation between `user`  and `DeviceTask`

Comment: In this case, you'll need to filter data by pivot table manually, instead of using relationships.